Need motor to stop at 4 different points for steering
Please see detail at the end which eplains the overall purpose of this project.
I'm building an electrical sports chair for disabled children.
One that is better in it's role than a wheelchair.
One that's fast and fun & allows them to play basketball against non-disabled children.
I have a 4 wheeled chair with 4 steerable wheels.
Powering is separate from direction control.
I wish to turn the direction that all wheels point wheels together so that the chair will move in the direction the wheels are pointing.
The wheels are mounted on a frame in the shape of an X.
Wheels are mounted at the end of each point of the X.
There are horizontal sprockets on top of each wheel with a bicycle chain running around all 4 wheel sprockets so that they can be all pointed in the same direction by moving the chain.
I want the direction of all 4 wheels to change at once and to be able to be stopped in one of 4 directions.
Direction change is controlled by a motor.
What do I need to do for the motor to stop at four different preset points?
------------------------------------------
Related information:
I'm planning on using a joystick for direction control.
I got four wheels that have motors in the wheels. Scooter wheels.
At present when I turn on the steering motor on all four wheels just spin on their vertical axis. I need to stop the motor at the four selected directions.
I can put a switch to stop the motor but I need to control the direction or where ever the motor stops that the only direction I can go in.

I'm building an electrical sports chair for disabled kids.
One that is better then a wheelchair.
One that's fast and fun & allows them to play basketball against non-disabled children.
One that means that you can't tell who is disabled & who isn't - All you see is two people playing in a fast fun chair. The wheels go up to 45 km & the chair goes 30 or more it's an engine motor.
As well as normal diractional steering I want it to be able to go from side 2 side or backwards and forwards really fast while maintaining it's "heading"  / direction so they can get around other people rapidly and give them the impression as if they are running.
Mechanically it's coming along great –
The steering is controlled by a motor driving a sprocket which in turn drives a chain which changes the pointing direction of all 4 wheels simultaneously.
The 4 wheels each have electrically powered e-scooter motors .
In the wheels wires go up the neck of the forks in the middle of the sprocket and they do not wind up . The wheels can rotate 360 and a motor does this and the chair rotates 360 as well and I side to side by a motor If I can stop it . So I want the wheels to be able to go in the opposite direction as the chair.
Please aske questions if further clarification is required.

Can you clarify what "four different points" means. I'm not sure if this question is about the mechanical connection of the four wheels, rather than the electronic control of the (unspecified) motor.

If the wheels are all connected by chain and sprocket then the problem can be reduced to stopping one wheel. It's not at all clear what your desired motion profile is and what a joystick has to do with it. A joystick has two axes of control - you only need one. What's supposed to happen if the joystick is held "on"? Draw a graph of the motion profile with angle of rotation on the x-axis and speed of rotation on the y-axis and post it in your question.

I got four wheels that have motors in the wheels . Scooter wheels . Now what I made is in the shape of an axe x so at the end of each point of the x I made it so they can turn by putti g sprockets on top of each wheel and i ran a chain to each wheel followi g the shape if the xall the way arond and back so the chain is a bike chain . The I got on top of one wheels two sprockets one that runs to each wheel and the other hook to a motor so the motor can turn them for me . When I turn the motor on all four wheels just spin . I need to stop the motor at the four points to move In that direction

So how do I stop the motor to go forward or to the left or right or to stop the motor at the point to drive backwards .I can put a switch to stop the motor but I need to control the direction or where ever the motor stops that the only direction I can go in . I want to be able to stop it to go in any direction I need to go in .

So when I sit in my chair I have one wheel in front of me one to the right one to the left and one wheel behind me . The all turn together cause I welded a sprocket to the top of them and ran a bike chain long enough to go around each sprocket but on top of one wheel I put two sprockets because the  wheels are able to turn all together now the other sprocket is to hook a chain to it for the motor to be able to spin all the wheels together.the motor just spins the wheels .I need to control the steering motor to stop at the four direction I can go in . And the wheels drive by there own motors .

One wheel each front, left, right&back is a very unusual design, having all wheels small is too. Turning all wheels in lock-step may allow to move in any direction you choose, but the chair keeps facing the same direction - perhaps recap what's common in ground vehicle steering?

@greybeard  It's a South-pointing Chariot :-)   https://wiki2.org/en/South-pointing_chariot

It sounds like this chair is intended to go forwards, backwards, crab-wise left and crab-wise right.  There's no way to turn around unless you can also control the motors to skid steer like a tank.

What you are trying to do is easy. But it is likely not practical. It would make more sense to steer the 2 front wheels or the 2 back wheels with the chain/sprocket idea to gain the lost degree of motion. Similar to a forklift.

I’m voting to close this question because this feels like a largely mechanical problem, and it's generating mechanical answers.  The General Engineering Stack might be a better fit.

@ScottSeidman  Thanks for explaining your close vote. Many don't who (IMHO) should. I agree that the general subject has a strong mechanaical component AND/BUT many motor control issues do. Position control (N steps or indexing or stop at home or ...) is an inseperable part of many motion control issues using electric motion means. Microswitches, hall switches, sensor pulse counters, .... are common electrical and electromechanical components.  Engineering group members (people acting as they do :-) ) may argue that it should be on EE.

Sorry guys I could explain it myself well . Was sure who could answer it . I just didn't know . The steering in being steered by a motor there is a fifth sprocket attached to the wheels and other sprockets . I'm building a chair that electrical with scooter motors . Motors in the wheels wires go up the neck of the forks in the middle of the sprocket . Can't wind up . The wheels can rotate 360 and a motor does this and the chair rotates 360 as well and I side to side by a motor If I can stop it . So I want the wheels to be able to go in the opposite direction as the chair

I'm trying to build an electrical sports chair for disabled kids one that better then a wheelchair . One that's fast fun & they can play basketball . I want to be able to use it to cause this way now you can't tell who is disabled  & who is . All you see is two people playing in a fast fun chair . The wheels go up to 45 km & the chair goes 30 or more it's an engine motor.  I want it to be abld to go from side 2 side really fast so they can get around other people and fast . Make it feel like they are running . I don't mean that in a bad way . I shouldntsay all this but it's coming along great

@ScottSeidman  Please see edited question.

James - I've edited your explanation into your questuion. It's best that you adexplanation to the question as well as to comments. || The situation is nowmuch clearer but not fully so. Does the chair change direction independent of the wheel X mount, and if so, how? Do you use differential wheel powering to steer the chair body?

"...  wires go up the neck of the forks in the middle of the sprocket and they do not wind up ..." Are you saying the forks can rotate infinitely without cable twisting to death? The steering scheme you are describing keeps the chair always pointing the same direction. How does the user turn it around?

The chair uses a motor to also rotate 360 degrees. So the wheels  got motors in them meaning brushless motors . Scooter wheels . The steering  uses a motor as well . And the wheels  can rotate 360 degrees . Meaning the steering . I just want to stop them at the four different directions you can go in .

So the bottom half has the four wheels inside it with the sorockets on top with chain going to each wheel . And a motor to steer them . All wheels turn at the same time . Now above that connected by a tube pipe is a chair which rotatesby a motor I welded a sprocket to the bottom of the chair and hooked a motor and chain up to it so it can spin left to right 360 degrees either way.

@JamesShea  Did you get what you were looking for here. If not I may be able to help re getting the question reopened OR advising another location to ask.

I'm thinking you can use a cam on the steering motor, fitted with a microswitch actuated by 4 detents, for each stop point.
It would work like this:

at rest: detent opens microswitch
twist joystick: energize motor, override microswitch, motor begins to move
release joystick: motor continues to move until next detent, then stops

Then:

move joystick forward / back: forward/reverse movement

So you'd 'bump-twist' the joystick to move one quadrant, or hold it for more than one. Then you'd push or pull the joystick to go forward or back.
This could be done entirely mechanically, other than regulating motor speed to make the movement less jerky. I would recommend a second microswitch to limit the rotation to +/- 2 quadrants from 'forward'.
But do you even need such a thing? You could dispense with the steering mechanism altogether and use skid-steering. This would be the mechanically simplest, yet more intuitive to operate, even allowing rotating in place, like a tank.
Or you can power only two of the wheels and let the others free-caster, like a power chair does.

If the question is worth answering you also may wish to consider upvoting it.  Entirely your choice.

@RussellMcMahon You're right, of course. It's too easy to forget to do that.

I think the question can be formulated as,


I want to use a joystick to move a chair in one of four directions, F (forward), B (backward), L (left) or (Right).
The chair has four motorised scooter wheels to drive.
The motorised wheels swivel in unison (sprocket and chain drive) with orientation control by electric steering motor.
How can I control this assuming the joystick uses normally open (NO) switch rather than potentiometers.


If this information is correct then you have the options of,

Drive motors only drive in one direction. Steering orients in F, R, B, L directions.
Drive motors are reversible. Steering orients in F and R directions only. (This still gives the ability to move in all four directions.)

I'll assume option 1.

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
Figure 1. A possible solution.
Assumptions:

Four-way joystick switch with NO contacts.
Four NC limit switches to detect steering orientation. (These can be mechanical, magnetic or proximity.)

How it's used:
The joystick is activated in the desired direction of travel. If the wheels are not pointing in that direction the steering motor runs until the direction is set. At that point the drive motors turn on.
How it works:

If joystick is in F position then RLY 2 is energised.
If the steering is not in the F position then F_LS will be closed, the steering motor will run and power will be cut to W1 to W4.
When F_LS opens steering orientation will stop and RLY1 will drop out. Power will then be applied to the wheel motors for as long as the joystick is held in the F position.
D1 to D4 prevent backfeed between the channels.

This arrangement has the disadvantage that a 90° change in direction may send the steering on a 270° rotation. It's simplicity may make this bearable.
Your question gives no indication about how power is delivered to the wheels. If it is by flexible cable rather than slip rings then the control will be more complex to avoid winding the cable around the steering shaft.

If the question is worth answering you also may wish to consider upvoting it.  Entirely your choice.

@RussellMcMahon, thanks, but it's not a good question yet.

My first thought is that you need some kind of information from the sprocket & chain mechanism, about its current position. One way of going about this is to have a fifth sprocket, which rotates with all the others, and at the same rate.
The difference with this particular wheel is that it has "bumps" welded onto it, or holes drilled through it. They would be used to deflect three micro-switch levers (like this, perhaps) as the wheel turns. Alternatively, shine light through the holes, which is detected by three photo-sensors.
There are three concentric rings of bumps/holes, inner (A), middle (B) and outer (C). Ring C has four bumps, positioned at 0°, 90°, 180° and 270°. That ring tells the controlling system when the wheel is positioned precisely at any one of those cardinal points.
Rings A and B encode a digital "signature" that identifies which of the points that the bump/hole on ring C is referring to. "1" is "bump/hole present", "0" is "bump/hole absent":



A
B
Position




0
0
0°


0
1
90°


1
0
180°


1
1
270°



The wheel might look like this:

Whichever technique you employ, you now have electrical signals telling the controller when the wheels are in one of the four positions, and which one, and this information will permit you to power the sprocket driving motor until the required condition is met.
The controller is another problem altogether. I'd use a microcontroller such as an ATMega (found on the Arduino Nano), which can process (in software) this position information, together with joystick position information, and respond by signalling an H-bridge motor controller (like this one) to apply motor power in one direction or the other.

If the question is worth answering you also may wish to consider upvoting it.  Entirely your choice.

As all the wheels are linked to the chain as you state, then all you need is to drill holes or indents at the 4 relevant points on the sprocket matching the 4 points you need.
A spring loaded ball will engage with each indent - this will provide sufficient locating force depending on the force applied by the spring and the shape of the indent. Giving a slope to the indent to allow the ball to leave easily will reduce the force needed to move it, having a deeper indent increases the force required.

I have four wheels they all have to turn at the same time so I can drive it . The steering is hook up to a motor . I need that motor to stop at four turning g points how do I get that motor to stop at each different points . If I turn the motor on all four wheels will just keep on spinning and I won't be able to drive anywhere .

Perhaps you need to explain that you need 4 wheels driven for movement AND 2 or 4 wheel steering. I assumed, from your basic description, that you were talking about steering.

So when I sit in my chair I have one wheel in front of me one to the right one to the left and one wheel behind me . The all turn together cause I welded a sprocket to the top of them and ran a bike chain long enough to go around each sprocket but on top of one wheel I put two sprockets because the wheels are able to turn all together now the other sprocket is to hook a chain to it for the motor to be able to spin all the wheels together.the motor just spins the wheels .I need to control the steering motor to stop at the four direction I can go in . And the wheels drive by there own motors .

If the question is worth answering you also may wish to consider upvoting it.  Entirely your choice.
